# Is there an easy way to copy files between servers using aptana?

Tags: aptana, scp

I have two Ubuntu servers.  One is my development box, the other is a production system.  They are not identical, though.  Most notably, the MySQL server is on a remote server from the production one whereas on the dev system it's on localhost.  Basically this means that I can *mostly* use a clone of the dev system, but if I just sync the filesystem the production system breaks.

Also, I am using Aptana (highly recommended, BTW).  Up until recently, I had a local copy of my development system as a project, but I just had to reformat.  I am not using a local project anymore, but instead I am using SFTP to connect with my Dev system and I am just editing files on there.  Up until now, I have just been SCPing only files that need updating to the production server from my local project, but I kind of like not having one.  I can restore it if necessary, though.

My question (short form): Is there an easy way using Aptana to copy files from one remote system to another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tim,

Currently you have to use local project (could be reconstructed from one remote) to synchronize two remote servers.
To enable auto-upload on local changes, in Project Explorer or App Explorer in context menu select Deploy/Deployment Settings, then check "Automatically sync my changes with the remote site".
This is all for Aptana Studio 3.

Cheers,
Max